# Python Beautiful Soup, how to retrieve the 'data-id'

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Im trying to figure out how i would extract the data-id from something 
like

```
<div class="tweet-text" data-id="1091362563202396165">
 dir="ltr" href="h" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" title=.html">cnbc.com/2019/02/01/non…</a>
</div>
```

I've tried `select('.data-id')`    also `d.get_text('data-id')` , `d.match('data-id')`.  I'm trying to extract the actual value in `data-id`, the number....                 Thanks for your help. I'll keep trying in the mean time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a search query of `attrs={"data-id": True}` to find elements that have a value for `data-id`.

```
for item in soupdata.find_all(attrs={"data-id": True}):
    print (item['data-id'])
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for answering..   i tried                                                                       for item in d.find_all(attr={'data-id': True}):
    print (item['data-id'])  but im still not getting any result....  is it my syntax?

Comment: It should be `attrs=`, not `attr=`.

Comment: Thanks John, I didnt realize you could just put true for the attribute value...   I was thinking i would have to use regex.....